# Multithreaded UDP client/server C#

Tags: c#, network-programming, udp, client, server

I am trying to get a multi-threaded UDP client/server going, but i'm running into problems on the server side. When a client attempts to register, a thread is created and all the interactions for that client are handled in that thread, but for some reason it only enters the thread once then exits right away.. can anyone help figure out why this happens? -Thanks in advance..

```
namespace AuctionServer
{
   class Program
   {
    public static Hashtable clientsList = new Hashtable();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //IPAddress ipAd = IPAddress.Parse("255.255.255.255");
        UdpClient server = new UdpClient(8888);
        IPEndPoint remoteEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
        string data = "";
        int listSize = 0;
        Console.WriteLine("Auction Server Started ....");
        listSize = clientsList.Count;

        while (true)
        {
            //Reads data
            byte[] inStream = server.Receive(ref remoteEndPoint);
            data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(inStream);
            //Console.WriteLine("REGISTER " + remoteEndPoint);

            if (!data.Contains("DEREGISTER "))
            {
                byte[] sendBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data + remoteEndPoint.ToString());
                server.Send(sendBytes, sendBytes.Length, remoteEndPoint);
                handleClinet client = new handleClinet();
                Console.WriteLine(data);
                clientsList.Add(data, server);
                client.startClient(server, data, clientsList, remoteEndPoint);
                data = "";
            }
        }
    }

    //Broadcast method is used to send message to ALL clients
    public static void broadcast(UdpClient dest, string msg, string uName, bool flag, IPEndPoint sendEP, Hashtable clientsList)
    {
        foreach (DictionaryEntry Item in clientsList)
        {
            Byte[] broadcastBytes = null;

            if (flag == true)
            {
                broadcastBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msg);
            }
            else
            {
                broadcastBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msg);
            }
            dest.Send(broadcastBytes, broadcastBytes.Length, sendEP);

        }
    }
}//end Main class
```

}

```
namespace AuctionServer
{
public class handleClinet
{
    UdpClient clientSocket;
    string clNo;
    Hashtable clientsList;
    IPEndPoint remoteIPEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
    IPEndPoint myEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);

    public void startClient(UdpClient inClientSocket, string clineNo, Hashtable cList, IPEndPoint tempEP)
    {
        this.myEP = tempEP;
        this.clientSocket = inClientSocket;
        this.clNo = clineNo;
        this.clientsList = cList;
        Thread ctThread = new Thread(doChat);
        ctThread.Start();
    }

    private void doChat()
    {
        int requestCount = 0;
        byte[] bytesFrom = new byte[10025];
        string dataFromClient = null;
        string rCount = null;
        requestCount = 0;

        while ((true))
        {
            try
            {
                //Thread.Sleep(1000);
                if (requestCount == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Thread Created");
                    requestCount++;
                }
                byte[] received = clientSocket.Receive(ref remoteIPEndPoint);
                dataFromClient = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(received);
                Console.WriteLine(dataFromClient);

                if (dataFromClient.Contains("DEREGISTER"))
                    clientSocket.Send(received, received.Length, remoteIPEndPoint);
                    //Program.broadcast(clientSocket, "DREG-CONF", clNo, true, myEP, clientsList);
                //else
                //    Program.broadcast(clientSocket, dataFromClient, clNo, true, myEP, clientsList);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                Console.ReadKey();
                break;
            }
        }//end while
    }//end doChat
```

}

Comment: Are you getting any exceptions at `        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());`?

Comment: I get no exceptions, the code is stuck in the Program.cs while loop instead of continually being in the thread's while loop.. @MarkSegal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two loops run on different threads. So the loop in `Main()` is executing concurrently with the loop in your `handleClinet` class.

If you want to switch to the `handleClinet` class's loop and debug it, then use the `Threads` window in the debugger (`Debug` menu, `Windows` menu item, then `Threads`...or press `Ctrl`-`D`, `T`) to switch to that thread. Then you can see the call stack and state of that thread.

Note that this may not work on the Express version of Visual Studio. I haven't tried the most recent version, but past versions did not support the `Threads` window. (You can still debug a specific thread by setting a breakpoint there…it's just that you can't switch to the thread manually).

Comment: I have debugged and i can't seem to figure out the problem. I want that when the client sends the server a "Register" command, the server creates a thread for that client and handles the communication in that thread. Is this possible? @PeterDuniho

Comment: I don't see what that has to do with the question of which threads are running. But no, not if the thread uses the same socket being used in some other thread. As I explained in response to your previous question, if you have two different threads reading from the same socket, you have no way to control which message gets read by which thread.

Comment: I just debugged using the Threads menu, and when i put breakpoints and check next statements with F10 the code seems to work fine.. but when i remove the breakpoints and run the code normally it doesn't work. Can you think of a reason for this? @PeterDuniho Thanks for your help by the way

Comment: Your previous comment helped me solve it! I couldn't start a thread  for every client on the same socket so i kept the communication in one thread and made an array of IPEndPoint to keep track of my clients. Thanks for your help @PeterDuniho

Comment: Excellent...glad to hear you sorted everything out. :)